# zsh: command not found: locust (although locust is already installed using pip on my ubuntu 19)

Tags: python, pip, command, zsh, locust

I installed locustio on my ubuntu using pip

```
"pip install locustio"
```

the problem is that everytime I run any locust command on my console (for example)

```
locust --version
```

the console returns this

```
zsh: command not found: locust
```

any solutions ?

Answer (score 5):

**here's a trick:**

1. write this command `pip uninstall locustio` in the console
2. this is what will be returned in the console

   `Uninstalling locustio-0.12.2:
     Would remove:
       /home/elta/.local/bin/locust
       /home/elta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/locust/*
       /home/elta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/locustio-0.12.2.dist-info/*
   Proceed (y/n)?`
3. write `n` , and copy the first directory which would be in my case
   `/home/elta/.local/bin/locust`
4. now this is the directory you gonna use every time to call locust command, for example

`/home/elta/.local/bin/locust --version`

.... not the best solution, but at works perfectly and did the trick

Comment: In this case you need to make sure that the directory `~/.local/bin` is available in your `$PATH` environment variable. I would start a new shell session and try the command `echo $PATH` to see if I find the directory mentioned above in there.

Comment: I ran the command and the directory is not there.. how to add it ?

Comment: You don't need to uninstall to see the locations of the files. `pip show --files locustio` does the trick.

Comment: it doesn't, the location returned is "/home/elta/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages" , which is not working

Comment: The trick works well for me, I have locust executable located under `/usr/local/bin` but `pip show --file` didn't show it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the scripts are installed in a directory that is available in your `PATH` environment variable.

Use `pip show --file locustio` to figure out where the scripts are installed (in your case: `~/.local/bin`). Modify your `PATH` to contain the directory where the scripts are installed. In your case, you probably should add something like the following to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
if [ -d "~/.local/bin" ] ; then
    export PATH="~/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Then the `locust` command should be available in all new shell sessions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to add it to PATH variable. You can locate it by running following commands

`sudo updatedb` This updates the internal DB of the OS which is used by locate command for file paths.

`locate locust`

This will give you location of locust which you can add to your PATH varible. And voila!!